# Speaker Wire Connection

Tags: speakers

I have some Phillip speakers I got from a friend, but they forgot to give me the amp. I'm hoping to still use these for some projects, but noticed the speaker wire coming out has two terminal, one wire marked with "+" and one wire marked with a number (I have 3 speakers, each is labeled "6", "7" or "8"). There are no colors to these wires. Is it safe to assume its a normal speaker where + is positive and the wire with the number is negative? I've never seen this before.

Comment: Did you ask your friend?  Model number?  Are these active speakers (including an amplifier) or just plain speakers?

Answer (score 1):

speakers take AC sighals so will not be harmed by reversed connections.

that said the + indicates the polarity of the speaker, connected backwards the speaker will create low pressure when it should create high pressure and high pressure when it should create low pressure,  the human ear cannot tell the difference, but when using several speakers it helps to have them correctly synchronised.

Comment: or explicitly invert one of them, depending on where the speaker is in relation to the listener and other speakers